# Java Collection with generic method and subclasses

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I've the following collection class that contains a method for grouping the elements in a map where each value has the type of the class invoking it

```
class TaskCollection<E extends Task> extends HashSet<E> {
    <K> Map<K, ? extends TaskCollection<E>> groupBy(Function<E, K> groupingFunction) {
        return this.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    groupingFunction,
                    Collectors.toCollection(this.collectionConstructor())
            ));
    }

    Supplier<? extends TaskCollection<E>> collectionConstructor() {
        return TaskCollection::new;
    }
}
```

What I want is to be able to create subclasses that use the `groupBy` method that returns new istances of themselves as map values.
The following is an example

```
class AssertionCollection extends TaskCollection<Assertion> {
    Map<Person, AssertionCollection> groupByPerson() {
        return this.groupBy(Assertion::assignedPerson);
    }

    @Override
    Supplier<AssertionCollection> collectionConstructor() {
        return AssertionCollection::new;
    }
}
```

The problem is in the `groupByPerson` method. The compiler throws an error for the `groupBy` call.

`Error:(15, 28) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) K exist so that java.util.Map<K,? extends TaskCollection<Assertion>> conforms to java.util.Map<Person,AssertionCollection>`

I'm new in Java so I'm pretty sure there's something stupid I don't see

Comment: A comment about your implementation: it seems that `TaskCollection` has a `HashSet` makes better sense than `TaskCollection` is a `HashSet`.  The use of `HashSet` feels like an implementation detail.  Do you need to inherit from `HashSet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intent is that for any class `X` that extends `TaskCollection`, when a groupBy operation is performed, the collection used for the map values are also instances of class `X`.

In that case, the closest you can get to that is something like the following:

```
class Task {}

class Assertion extends Task {}

abstract class TaskCollection<E extends Task, C extends TaskCollection<E, C>> extends HashSet<E> {

    <K> Map<K, C> groupBy(Function<E, K> groupingFunction) {
        return this.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    groupingFunction,
                    Collectors.toCollection(this.collectionSupplier())
            ));
    }

    protected abstract Supplier<C> collectionSupplier();
}

class AssertionCollection extends TaskCollection<Assertion, AssertionCollection> {

    @Override
    protected Supplier<AssertionCollection> collectionSupplier() {
        return AssertionCollection::new;
    }
}
```

Notice that the definition of `TaskCollection` above does not quite stop subclasses of using another `TaskCollection` class for their groupBy map values. For example this would also compile:

```
class AssertionCollectionOther extends TaskCollection<Assertion, AssertionCollectionOther> {...}

class AssertionCollection extends TaskCollection<Assertion, AssertionCollectionOther> {...}
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to impose such a constraint, at least for now, as you cannot make reference to the class that is being declared in the C type-parameter wildcard.

If you can assume that descendants have a parameter free constructor as the collection supplier you can provide a default implementation for 
`collectionSupplier`. The price you pay is the need to silence a "unchecked" warning (not a real problem) and that not compliant classes (not providing the parameter-free constructor) won't fail at compilation time but at run-time which is less ideal:

```
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Task {}

class Assertion extends Task {}

class TaskCollection<E extends Task, C extends TaskCollection<E, C>> extends HashSet<E> {

    <K> Map<K, C> groupBy(Function<E, K> groupingFunction) {
        return this.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    groupingFunction,
                    Collectors.toCollection(this.collectionSupplier())
            ));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected Supplier<C> collectionSupplier() {
       return () -> {
         try {
          return (C) this.getClass().newInstance();
         } catch (Exception ex) {
          throw new RuntimeException(String.format("class %s is not a proper TaskCollection", this.getClass()), ex);
         }
      };
    }
}

class AssertionCollection extends TaskCollection<Assertion, AssertionCollection> {
    // This override is not needed any longer although still could
    // be included in order to produce a slightly faster 
    // customized implementation:
    //@Override
    //protected Supplier<AssertionCollection> collectionSupplier() {
    //    return AssertionCollection::new;
    //}
}
```

If you declare `collectionSupplier` as `final` you would effectively force subclasses to always return instances of their own class with the caveat that a, then non-sense, declaration such as `class AssertionCollection extends TaskCollection<Assertion, AssertionCollectionOther>` would still compile and produce run-time cast exceptions down the road.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: I having deleted my ugly answer. nice answer, and up vote.